# Ubuntu Network manager keeps asking for Wi-fi password

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking

I've been running 12.10 on my laptop for almost a year, never had any problems. Since yesterday, however, I can't connect to my home network. Ubuntu just keeps asking for the network key, and I am sure I'm writing the correct one. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and WPA encryption.

I've already tried to "forget" the network, restarting network-manager, unchecking "available to all users" as suggested in answers to similar questions, but nothing seems to work. I have a desktop running 13.04 and it works flawlessly, no issues whatsoever.

Are there any other ways/workarounds to fix this? Was this caused by some recent updates to 12.10?